# Add custom data with ForegroundColorSpan

Tags: android-edittext, android

I'm using `ForegroundColorSpan` to highlight some portion of my text in `EditText`.

> Jeff feeling hungry at **NorthBay**.

In above example, I've to identify NorthBay based on its id in my db. Later on, I have to perform some querying based on this id. Apparently there seems no way to add custom data to `ForegroundColorSpan` instance. What could be a possible workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the solution myself. I created a custom span class as;

```
public static class MySpan extends ForegroundColorSpan {

    private Object instance;

    public Object getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public void setInstance(Object instance) {
        this.instance = instance;
    }

}
```

Then used this span on to style substring in textview.